# Determine if Makefile is executed with gmake

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, freebsd

Say on FreeBSD an application needs to be compiled with GNU make (gmake), not the standard system make. Is there any directive I could put to the Makefile to stop executing it and print an error if the Makefile is not compiled with gmake?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Call your makefile `GNUmakefile`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Names). GNU Make will find it, but not other makes.

> The first name checked, GNUmakefile, is not recommended for most makefiles. You should use this name if you have a makefile that is specific to GNU make, and will not be understood by other versions of make. Other make programs look for makefile and Makefile, but not GNUmakefile.

Comment: Interesting approach. Say the user wants to compile an application on FreeBSD. They type in 'make' and nothing happens (make says there is no target to make as it can't find the makefile). User has no clue that it needs to be compiled with gmake until they check the folder and know what GNUmake means. Probably not a big problem but I was hoping for a more user friendly solution.

Comment: @Amiramix: Then how about *also* having a `makefile` with a single rule: `all: ; @echo use GNUMake`

Comment: @Beta: How about a rule of the form: `$(MAKECMDGOALS): ; @echo Use GNU Make`?

Comment: @Beta: Don't feel too bad. You're still beating me in the [tag:make], [tag:makefile] and [tag:gnu-make] tags.

Comment: That does make me feel better. I mean, knowing that you're tracking those stats and feeling bad.

Comment: @Beta: I will overtake you eventually. Your days at the top are numbered.

Comment: I guess they must be numbered greater than one: `.PHONY: $(MAKECMDGOALS)`

Answer (score 3):

**This is an addon to Jack Kelly's answer.**

After you have renamed your Makefile to GNUmakefile create Makefile with:

```
USEGNU=gmake $*
all:
    @$(USEGNU)
.DEFAULT:
    @$(USEGNU)
```

This will call gmake for you every time you run make.

Comment: That's a nice solution.