# Testing that a makefile is being evaluated by gmake

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is it possible to have a check within a makefile that gmake is being used instead of BSD make?

Or am I stuck with the sledgehammer approach of GNUmakefile which seems a bit a inelegant and definitely not user friendly?

@Amiramix expresses my reservations succinctly in his comment to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11776785/2974) to the same question.

**Edit:** If BSD make is being used to evaluate the Makefile then I'd like it to bail and bleat that gmake should be run to evaluate the Makefile instead.

**Edit 2:** I've taken the now sadly deleted answer from @devnull and played with it a bit to get it to:

```
MAKEVERSION=Not_GNU

checkVariant:
        @MAKEVERSION=`${MAKE} --version 2>/dev/null | head -1 | sed -e 's/^\(GNU\).*$/\1/'`; \
        if [ "${MAKEVERSION}" != "GNU" ]; then \
            echo "Not using gmake"; \
            exit 1; \
        fi
```

but the sed complains that the command, which works fine on the command line, is garbled.

I'll come back when I get a chance to play further.

Comment: What do you want BSD Make to do if it runs the makefile?

Comment: Cheers @Beta I've added an edit to explain.

Comment: @devnull could you please restore your answer as I think I have an edit for it that gets me much closer

Comment: Why don't you just test to see if a variable that GNU make defines, that other makes don't (by default), is defined?  For example the `$(.FEATURES)` variable which is available in GNU make 3.81 or newer.  If you want to support older versions of GNU make you can use one of the other built-in variables.  Then just `[ -n '$(.FEATURES)' ] || { echo please use gnu make; exit 1; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that the set of *portable* make constructs is extremely anemic.  There are many variables you can test to see if you're using GNU make, but any tests such as this must be done using the shell, and that means inside a recipe, to be portable.  That means that all targets in your makefile must list the "test for GNU make" target as a prerequisite, to ensure the test is done first.

Even more problematic is that it means you cannot use a large variety of GNU make constructs since they will be syntax errors in other versions of make, long before make gets around to running your rule that tests for GNU make-ness.

The GNUmakefile trick will work, but it's not pleasant I agree.  The other option is to have your Makefile with nothing but a `.DEFAULT` target, which does the test then invokes `$(MAKE) -f realMakefile $@` and have all the rest of your make content in `realMakefile`.  `.DEFAULT` is defined by the POSIX standard but I don't know how many other make implementations actually provide it.  It's still a bit unpleasant because if you run `make foo bar baz` then the recursive make is invoked 3 times.

Or, you can just document the prerequisite in the README file and hope people read it if their implementation of make spits a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that we're basically left trying to build a rule using a set of basic contructs available to us from the set created in the 1970's (with _some_ extensions of course).